# Having problems previewing XAML design in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: wpf, xaml

I've cloned the https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit github and when I try to preview the design in VS2019 I can't, it keeps telling me name "x" does not exist in namespace "http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes" **but I can compile and run the program successfully**.

Am I missing out anything??

[image: Problem Previewing XAML]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I chat with stranger online who's using this Nuget Package and he's experiencing the same issue too so I guess this is a bug from the package.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add to it, make sure you locate the paths correctly and try again.

Hopefully! Yr compile was successfully without any error it should kick start and if it does not, then check the bug and make any updates available